# How do I clean up the config data left behind by VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS code has left behind a rather large amount of stuff(2GB) in my `~/.config` directory. I was wondering what might be same to delete, and how to keep it from growing this big in the future.

It appears that most of the stuff is in `~/.config/Code/User`.